# Xming with windows 8 to a unix computer

Tags: windows, linux, windows-8, ssh, x11-forwarding

Ok. So I am just getting started with this whole xming thing but I encountered an error which I can't really find a suitable solution for on the many forums that discuss xming. I installed xming, xlaunch, the xming fonts and I have had putty for a while now. I loaded an IP address that I frequently use and changed it to allow x11 forwarding. I logged into the unix computer and it automatically added a Xauthority file (or something along those lines). I closed the session, restarted my computer and tried to begin xming with the Xlaunch. 
I chose multiple windows, display number 0, Start a program, Start program xterm using PuTTY (plink.exe) and I put the IP that I have used in PuTTY previously.I enter my user and pass the same as usual. But unfortunately it keeps kicking me out saying that the host does not exist.

SO:
TLDR- I have downloaded xming to the best of my ability, based on what the many online tutorials say. Using standard log ins (that I normally use in PuTTY) I am getting a host not found error. How can I solve my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually gave up and installed/reinstalled and the problem seemed to fix itself.